# variable bitrate streaming under linux

Tags: linux, video, streaming, vlc-media-player, ffmpeg

i know that in Linux i can stream using vlc and ffmpeg. i was able to successfully stream using vlc but only in static bitrates. i must set 400k/s or 800k/s. i want it to use as much upload bandwidth as it can consume. so if my internet line is not busy and i'm not downloading anything the quality will be better. is it possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

darwin opensource streaming server supports variable bitrate streaming.